# Bootstrap PHP Contact Form Not Sending Email?

Tags: php, forms

I have done several searches, and I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Im using bootstrap and a php contact form for a user to input data. This was my reference to building that form: http://rosstanner.co.uk/2012/11/build-simple-contact-form-html-php-bootstrap/

Im able to successfully post in the form, and receive my success or failure alert. However, the email is not actually being sent. My email is in the php file that the form is being redirected to, but is not receiving anything (yes I have checked my spam).

I want to check if there is something server side I am missing (module wise for php). I've just installed LAMP and left it at that. The site works fine, but the form wont post an email.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your setup and code, and by looking at the link in your post, I would guess that your PHP.ini file is not setup.

For PHP to be able to send a mail it will need to use an SMTP server. I know a lot of people use Googles (if you have an account) as it's pretty trusted.

There is a great article on setting up your PHP.ini file below:
http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Another alternative is to install your own mail server. But I wouldn't necessarily recommend this due to problems with SPAM if it is not secured properly.

Comment: this is what I see in my php.ini file in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:            ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

Comment: Im using Ubuntu-server*

Comment: Im going to try using this method to set up my php.ini: http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.com/2010/04/sending-emails-from-ubuntu-without.html

Comment: So I am able to send mail from terminal within my ubuntu server, but using the exact copied code and structure from above (minus changing my the address to my address), I am unable to get an email to send. Any thoughts?